# Update a text file with python only if it has changed

Tags: python, linux

Ok, I have my raspberry pi hooked up to a magnetic sensor on my garage door. I have a python script that update a website (initailstate.com) every second and reports changes, but it costs money after 25k requests and I killed that very quickly lol. 
I want to instead to update a text file every time the state of the door changes.(open/closed) I have a text file called data.txt. I have a web page that uses java script to read the txt file and uses ajax to update and check the file for changes. this all works as i want but how can i get python to update a text file if and only if the contents of the file are different?

I am looking to use python to update the text file once the door changes states. I could use a database but I figured a text file would be easier to start with.
Let me know what you need from me if i haven't been specific enough.

Comment: Closing as too broad. Please note that [so] is not to provide you with all the code that you need. (You might find help on Codementor or Airpair). See [how] and what is a [mcve]

Comment: You could look at `os.stat` and see if the modification times of the file has changed since last you looked.

Comment: I have a script that updates a webservice. how can i update a text file instead. I would be ok with overwriting the file with new contents

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like this:

```
f = open("state.txt", "w+") # state.txt contains "True" or "False"

def get_door_status():
    # get_door_status() returns door_status, a bool
    return door_status

while True:
    door_status = str(get_door_status())
    file_status = f.read()
    if file_status != door_status:
        f.write(door_status)
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with small files that are exclusive to you, simply cache their content. This is faster and healthier for your storage.

```
# start of the script
# load the current value
import ast
status, status_file = False, "state.txt"
with open(status_file) as stat_file:
    status = ast.literal_eval(next(stat_file()))

# keep on looping, check against *known value*
while True:
    current_status = get_door_status()
    if current_status != status:  # only update on changes
        status = current_status  # update internal variable
        # open for writing overwrites previous value
        with open(status_file, 'w') as stat_file:
            stat_file.write(status)
```